# Linux: how to suppress listing loop devices when using mount command?

Tags: linux, mount, loopback

Is there a way to prevent including loop devices when using `mount` command on its own in order to list existing mounts?

When there are dozens of loopback devices it's tedious having to sift through the output for 'real' hardware mounts.

Of course, I could use something like `mount | grep -v squashfs | grep -v loop` but is there a better way?

Comment: run the output through a filter

Comment: @jsotola: yeah, I could grep, awk etc, but I would like to figure out if there a better way

Comment: create an `alias` for the filtered command

Comment: yes, the intent _is_ to create an alias, but avoid raw grepping and use `mount` alone

Comment: Also related, this answer on Unix&Linux - [Showing only "interesting" mount points / filtering non interesting types](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/177014/100397)

Comment: @ChrisDavies: thanks! learned something new! one thing that `findmnt -t ext4` doesn't seem to provide is listing the device label, which is available eg via `mount -l -t ext4`

Comment: @ccpizza `man findmnt` will show you how to get labels: `findmnt --output TARGET,SOURCE,FSTYPE,OPTIONS,LABEL`

Comment: `findmd` is indeed very versatile! thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

##### `mount`

`mount` doesn't have an option to exclude specific file system types, but `-t <some-type>` can be used on its own without specifying a device — in this case `mount` will list only file systems of the given type. As the `-t` switch can  accept multiple file system types, a possible alias for listing only 'real' disks and ignore everything else (e.g `tmpfs`, `squashfs`, `ramfs`, `sysfs` etc) could be something like (`-l` adds the label):

```bash
mount -l -t ext4,ext3,ext2,ntfs3,ntfs-3g,hfsplus,fat,vfat,exfat
```

##### `findmnt`

As commented by @ChrisDavies the same and more can be achieved with `findmnt` as described in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177040/15312), including the ***-i***nversion of the filesystem types, e.g. list all file systems except the specified type (`-i` stands for invert):

```bash
findmnt -it tmpfs,squashfs,fuse.lxcfs,binfmt_misc,hugetlbfs,devtmpfs,proc,sysfs,securityfs,devpts,cgroup,cgroup2,pstore,bpf,autofs,mqueue,rpc_pipefs,debugfs,tracefs,configfs,nfsd,fusectl,fuse.gvfsd-fuse

# same as above but with custom columns, `df` style
findmnt -it tmpfs,squashfs,fuse.lxcfs,binfmt_misc,hugetlbfs,devtmpfs,proc,sysfs,securityfs,devpts,cgroup,cgroup2,pstore,bpf,autofs,mqueue,rpc_pipefs,debugfs,tracefs,configfs,nfsd,fusectl,fuse.gvfsd-fuse -o LABEL,SOURCE,FSTYPE,SIZE,USED,AVAIL,USE%,TARGET

## example output:
# LABEL  SOURCE         FSTYPE   SIZE   USED  AVAIL USE% TARGET
# rootfs /dev/mmcblk0p2 ext4      57G  38.4G  16.3G  67% /
# boot   /dev/mmcblk0p1 vfat     255M  51.7M 203.3M  20% ├─/boot
# ext3   /dev/sda3      ext3   825.5G 721.6G  61.9G  87% ├─/media/usb0
```

##### `lsblk -f`

Yet another way is `lsblk -f` which generates output like this:

```bash
# NAME        FSTYPE  FSVER LABEL  UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
# sda
# ├─sda1      vfat    FAT32 EFI    4860-1E0F
# ├─sda2      hfsplus       machfs ee5f1caa-d14b-369f-9f2a-161000514cd9
# └─sda3      ext3    1.0   ext3   e3ad15e9-7640-44f1-af6c-f2d535fcf218   61.9G    87% /media/usb0
# mmcblk0
# ├─mmcblk0p1 vfat    FAT32 boot   D386-9DE9                             203.3M    20% /mnt/mmcblk0p1
# └─mmcblk0p2 ext4    1.0   rootfs 996c1b5f-170b-4f38-a5e0-85eef5acf12c   16.3G    67% /mnt/mmcblk0p2
```

> As seen from the output above, `lsblk -f` has a potential advantage over `mount` and `findmnt` as it also shows partitions **that are not currently mounted**.

Similar to `findmnt` you can configure the columns you want with `lsblk`, for example add the total device size (`SIZE`), partition type (`PTTYPE`), uuid (`UUID`), partition UUID (`PARTUUID`):

```bash
lsblk -f -o NAME,LABEL,FSTYPE,SIZE,FSAVAIL,FSUSE%,MOUNTPOINT,PTTYPE,UUID,PARTUUID
# NAME        LABEL  FSTYPE    SIZE FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT     PTTYPE UUID                                 PARTUUID
# sda                          1.8T                               gpt
# ├─sda1      EFI    vfat      200M                               gpt    4860-1E0F                            b88cc4b9-4c97-4370-9cc7-ce084f43efc9
# ├─sda2      machfs hfsplus     1T                               gpt    ee5f1caa-d14b-369f-9f2a-161000514cd9 d8ca0df7-e060-4bcc-84a6-b014441cf5f4
# └─sda3      ext3   ext3    838.8G   61.9G    87% /media/usb0    gpt    e3ad15e9-7640-44f1-af6c-f2d535fcf218 272d223e-3eb5-4cd1-be54-81924a16db82
# mmcblk0                     58.2G                               dos
# ├─mmcblk0p1 boot   vfat      256M  203.3M    20% /mnt/mmcblk0p1 dos    D386-9DE9                            cd6fc030-01
# └─mmcblk0p2 rootfs ext4       58G   16.3G    67% /mnt/mmcblk0p2 dos    996c1b5f-170b-4f38-a5e0-85eef5acf12c cd6fc030-02
```